# Where is the redirect_uri set when using facebook login for a web app?

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I have an angular-ui-router web app.

There's code:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    console.log('loginCtrl.window.fbAsyncInit: initiating FB ...');
    FB.init({
        appId: '1058057514286456', // rand's peoplecount-www app
        //status: true,
        //cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        version: 'v2.5'
    });
(function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {
        return;
    }
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

When I click on the login-with-facebook button, it calls:

```
FB.login(function (response) {
    console.log('FB Reg : Response - ' + JSON.stringify(response));
    if (response.authResponse) {
        console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
        FB.api('/me', {fields: 'name, email,first_name,last_name,verified'}, function (response) {
            $scope.saveUserInfo('$scope.fbRegistration', response);
            console.log('fbReg: api response='+JSON.stringify(response));
        });
    } else {
        console.log('fbReg: User cancelled login or did not fully authorize. response='+JSON.stringify(response));
    }
});
```

When I hit the facebook login button, I a facebook dialog opens with a message:

```
URL Blocked
This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted
in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth
Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs.
```

What redirect URI is it using?  Where do I set it?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web === nothing on this web page talks about the redirect URI

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow === this has a call to a url with a redirect_uri on it. Do I have to use this manual method?

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
    client_id={app-id}
    &redirect_uri={redirect-uri}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All redirect URI should be whitelisted in the App's Dashboard.
The Dashboard can be accessed at https://developers.facebook.com/

[image: Products]

Under **PRODUCTS** category you should see "**Facebook Login**" (if not - just create it through "+Add Product" option)
On the "Facebook Login" you'll find "**Valid OAuth redirect URIs**" parameter where you can whitelist your URIs.

[image: AuthO]

Facebook security guys explains why it may be necessary https://www.facebook.com/FacebookforDevelopers/videos/10152795636318553/ at around 9:50.

Starting March 2018 only such whitelisted URIs will be able call Facebook API.